# XSLT: stop list output on condition if-test (or something)

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, conditional-statements

I've got an XBEL formatted XML-file. The out-put is a nested list. I wish to out-put only till the 2nd level (included) of the nodes named 'folder'. The match rule is set accordingly in the template.
Of course the resulting HTML output contains an empty -tag. How can I do this properly, so that the template stops producing output **before** creating empty `<ul>`-tags (without `<li>`-tags)?
I assume the solution is in specifying the test-condition properly.

The Template:

```
<xsl:template match="xbel/folder/folder/folder" mode="subfolderlist">
    <li>
        <span class="folderTitleLink"><xsl:value-of select="title" /></span>
    </li>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="subfolderlist" />
</xsl:template>
```

The XSLT:

```
...<!--<xsl:if test="not(xbel/folder/folder/folder)">-->
<xsl:if test="(child::folder)">     <!--do it as long as there are subfolders, the last node gets never listed-->
    <div class="level-2">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="subfolderlist" />
        </ul>
    </div>
</xsl:if>...
```

The XML structure:

```
<xbel>
<folder folded="yes">
    <title>bookmarks</title>
    <desc>my bookmarks</desc>

    <folder folded="no">
        <title>Level-1</title>
        <desc>bla1</desc>
        <bookmark href="http://www.xyz.com/">
            <title>BM1-Level1</title>
            <desc>Desc-BM1-Level1</desc>
        </bookmark>

        <folder folded="no">
            <title>Level-2</title>
            <desc>bla2</desc>
            <bookmark href="http://www.xyz.com/">
                <title>BM1-Level2</title>
                <desc>Desc-BM1-Level2</desc>
            </bookmark>

            <folder folded="no">
                <title>Level-3</title>
                <desc>bla3</desc>
                <bookmark href="http://www.xyz.com/">
                    <title>BM1-Level3</title>
                    <desc>Desc-BM1-Level3</desc>
                </bookmark>

                <folder folded="no"> 
                    <title>Level-4</title>
                    <desc>bla4</desc>
                    <bookmark href="http://www.xyz.com/">
                        <title>BM1-Level4</title>
                        <desc>Desc-BM1-Level4</desc>
                    </bookmark>
                </folder>
            </folder>
        </folder>
    </folder>
</folder></xbel>
```

here

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the match patterns and test condition you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to have a template with a match pattern as the following**:

```
<xsl:template match="folder[not(ancestor::folder[3])]" 
              mode="subfolderlist"> 

  <!-- Your processing here -->

</xsl:template>
```

**Also, replace this**:

```
<xsl:if test="(child::folder)">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:if test="folder and not(ancestor::folder[2])">
```

Comment: One more question on this topic: Would you please elaborate on this match, I don't really get it. `(ancestor::folder)` returns the number of ancestors of the current node. The `[3]` limits the match (depth) of nodes named folder. The `'not'` turns the whole into the opposite. Why? Something in my reflection must be wrong.

Comment: @snahl: `not(ancestor::folder[2])` means "has one or none ancestors named `folder` " -- but not two or more. `ancestor::folder[2]` is the "second ancestor named `folder` (upwards)`. The function `not(aNode)` evaluates to `true()` only when the node `aNode` exists.